# Adapter/Wrapper and equal references

Tags: c#, .net, adapter

I want to create a wrapper class for another type. This works fine until the point where it's necessary that (reference)-equal objects need to have (reference)-equal wrappers.

An example:

```cs
public interface ITest<T>
{
    T GetInstance(bool createNew);
}

public class Test : ITest<Test>
{
    private static Test instance;

    public Test GetInstance(bool createNew)
    {
        if (instance == null || createNew)
        {
            instance = new Test();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}


public class TestWrapper : ITest<TestWrapper>
{
    private readonly Test wrapped;
    public TestWrapper(Test wrapped)
    {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    public TestWrapper GetInstance(bool createNew)
    {
        return new TestWrapper(wrapped.GetInstance(createNew));
    }
}
```

`Test.GetInstance` returns always the same instance, as long as the parameter `createNew` is `false`.
By contrast `TestWrapper.GetInstance` returns always a new instance.

Since I want to be able to replace `Test` with `TestWrapper`, I search for a solution so that at the end, the wrapper returns a new instance only, if Test returns a new instance. However, the TestWrapper should have no knowledge about the internals of Test.

The test code is

```cs
private static void RunTest<T>(ITest<T> cls)
{
    var i1 = (ITest<T>)cls.GetInstance(false);
    var i2 = (ITest<T>)cls.GetInstance(false);
    var i3 = (ITest<T>)cls.GetInstance(true);

    var dic = new Dictionary<ITest<T>, bool>();
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(i1)) dic.Add(i1, false); else dic[i1] = true;
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(i2)) dic.Add(i2, false); else dic[i2] = true;
    if (!dic.ContainsKey(i3)) dic.Add(i3, false); else dic[i3] = true;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dic.Select(a => a.Value.ToString())));
}
```

The desired result is

```cs
True, False
```

and that's what you get if one passes `new Test()` to that method.
If you pass `new TestWrapper(new Test())`, you'll get

```cs
False, False, False
```

There is a solution based on a simple cache (`Dictionary<Test, TestWrapper>`) - but with that, I would hold many of the instances in memory without using them any further (and the GC could not collect those instances since there's a reference holding them).

I played around with `WeakReferences` a bit, but I can't spot a key that I can use to store the `WeakReference` - thus I have to iterate through the cache list and search for the correct instance which is slow. Besides, I've to implement this solution for every member (with it's very own cache) which seems not to be a great solution...

I hope I have adequately explained my problem ;) So, my questions are:

- <del>is there a way to cheat `object.ReferenceEquals`</del> (that question is unrewarding)
- what can I use (as a key for the cache) as an identifier for an object instance (so I can use `WeakReference`)
- is there a better way to achieve a real adapter (where I can replace the adaptee with an adapter without headache)

I've no access to the `Test` class, and only limited access to the code that uses it (I'm able to pass an arbitrary instance as long it's implements the interface)

Comment: You can't cheat `object.ReferenceEquals()`, but that's the reason `object.Equals()` is virtual, and why we have things like `IEqualityComparer`. *Why* do you need `ReferenceEquals()` to return true here?

Comment: Have you tried to override `==` operator: `public static bool operator ==(T1 obj1, T2 obj2)`.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: **I** do not need ReferenceEquals to be true ;). The runtime need it in order to get things right.
E.g. if the instance is used as a key in an Dictionary<>.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo: yes, I tried it. The Problem is not `ReferenceEquals` itself, but equal references. I need an approach, with that I can return the very same adapter-instances, if the adaptee-member returns the very same instances...

Comment: @WolfgangKluge No, you don't need that at all.  You just need the type to define how it considers objects to be equal, rather than using the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't cheat `object.ReferenceEquals()`. However, `object.ReferenceEquals()` is intentionally used *very rarely*, and usually in cases where things really do need to be reference-equal.

> The runtime need it in order to get things right. E.g. if the instance is used as a key in an `Dictionary<>`

Actually, the runtime typically uses the `.GetHashCode()` and `.Equals()` behavior of the individual objects, but it just so happens that if you don't override that behavior in your classes, the base `System.Object` implementation of those methods relies on the object reference by default.

So if you have the ability to change the code for both the `Test` class and the `TestWrapper` class, you can override these equality methods in those classes to ensure that they recognize equivalent objects as equal.

An alternative (and usually better) approach would be to create an `IEqualityComparer<>` implementation to use in your specific use case. You mentioned keys in a `Dictionary<>`: you can provide an `IEqualityComparer<>` instance to the dictionary when it's created to have it test for equality in exactly the way you want.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<object, object(new TestsAndWrappersAreEqualComparer());
var test = Test.GetInstance(true);
var testWrapper = TestWrapper.GetInstance(true);
dict[test] = test;
Console.WriteLine(dict.ContainsKey(test)); // true
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. `GetHashCode` and `Equals` are sufficient for `ContainsKey` just as you explained (and the overrides are called).
Thanks! So at the end it's not the very same, but similar enough ;)